# How Can I Create A BigDecimal Object that has null as it's value

Tags: java, junit, bigdecimal

I have a java program that I am testing and a lot of the code is centered around the idea that a coin can have a value null. The issue, the coin is defined using Coin(BigDecimal) and I cannot figure out how to convert the Bug Decimal Part to represent null.

Comment: `BigDecimal d = null;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign `null` to your `BigDecimal` reference variable, as you would for any other class.

Example class defined as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
record Coin ( String name , BigDecimal monetaryValue ) {}
```

Usage with null.

```java
record Coin( String name , BigDecimal monetaryValue ) { }
Coin c = new Coin ( "Mystery" , null );
```

> c.toString() = Coin[name=Mystery, monetaryValue=null]

Answer (score 0):

You can define [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO) your coin variable instead of defining null.

According to document

[Docs Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

> All methods and constructors for this class throw NullPointerException when passed a null object reference for any input parameter.